# How to insert new node in TreePanel in ExtJS4?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I would like to insert a new node into my Tree.
I develop with Sencha library version 4.
TreeNode seems not working ... Firebug error :

> Erreur : uncaught exception: Ext.Loader is not enabled, so dependencies cannot be resolved dynamically. Missing required class: Ext.tree.TreeNode

I have add Loader config enable : true . it don't work too ...  !

My code :

```
    /*Ext.Loader.setConfig({
            enabled: true
});
*/
Ext.require([

    'Ext.form.*',
    'Ext.grid.*',
    'Ext.tree.*',
    'Ext.data.*',
    'Ext.util.*',
    'Ext.loader.*',
    'Ext.state.*',
    'Ext.layout.container.Column',
    'Ext.tab.TabPanel'

]);


Ext.onReady(function(){

     Ext.QuickTips.init();

        Ext.define('Task', {
            extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields : [ 
                { name : 'id', type :'int'},
                { name : 'task', type : 'string' },
                { name : 'material', type : 'string'},
                {name : 'cc' ,  type : 'string'},
                { name : 'date_debut', type : 'string'}
            ]
        });

        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore',{

                model : 'Task',
                proxy : {
                    type : 'ajax',
                    url : 'myjson.json'

                },
                folderSort: true
        });

        var tree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.TreePanel',{

            title : 'Task Manager',
            width :1000,
            height : 400,
            //renderTo : Ext.getBody(),
            collapsible : true,
            useArrows : true,
            rootVisible : false,
            store : store,
            multiSelect : true,
            itemId : 'id',
            singleExpand : true,
            tbar : [
                {
                    xtype : 'button' , text : 'ADD TASK ', 
                    handler : function(){ 

                        var selectedItem = tree.getSelectionModel().getSelection();

                            if(!selectedItem){

                                selectedItem = tree.getRootNode();
                            }

                            handleCreate = function(btn, text,cBoxes){
                                if(btn=='ok' && text){

                                        //alert('oui');
                                        //var newNode = new Ext.tree.TreeNode({});
                                        var newNode = Ext.create('Ext.tree.TreeNode',{

                                                id : '0',
                                                task : text,
                                                material : 'New Material',
                                                cc : 'new CC',
                                                date_debut :'00/00/00',

                                                leaf : false,
                                                allowChildren : false
                                        });
                                        if(selectedItem.isLeaf()) {
                                            selectedItem.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, selectedItem.nextSibling);
                                        } else {
                                            selectedItem.insertBefore(newNode, selectedItem.firstChild);
                                        }
                                }else{
                                    alert('non');
                                }

                            }
                        Ext.MessageBox.show({
                            title:'Add new Folder Item',
                            msg: 'Name of Folder Item:',
                            buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OKCANCEL,
                            prompt:true,
                            fn: handleCreate
                        });
                        }

                }

            ],
            listeners : {
                itemclick : function(a,b,c,d,e){
                        var size = b.length;
                    //  alert(d + ' ' + b.toString()+' b size = '+size+' e ' + e + ' a ' + a);
                        if( b instanceof Task){
                                // Form = les champs dans le form editable
                                var form = fields.getForm();
                                //Chaque field de la zone d'edition
                                var fId = form.findField('id');
                                var ftask = form.findField('task');
                                var fmaterial = form.findField('material');
                                var fcc = form.findField('cc');
                                var fStartDate = form.findField('start_date');

                                fId.setValue(b.get('id'));
                                ftask.setValue(b.get('task'));
                                fmaterial.setValue(b.get('material'));

                        }

                }
            },
            //plugins: [cellEditing],

            columns : [{
                text : 'ID',
                dataIndex : 'id',
                sortable : true,
                width : 50      
            },{
                xtype : 'treecolumn',
                text : 'Task',
                flex : 2,
                sortable : true,
                dataIndex : 'task',
                width : 100
            },
            {
                text : 'Material',
                dataIndex : 'material',
                width : 100
            },
            {
                text :  'CC',
                dataIndex : 'cc',
                width : 100

            },
            {
                text : 'Date_Debut',
                dataIndex : 'date_debut',
                width : 100
            }]                          


        });
        var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
        data : [
            {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
            {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
            {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"}

            ]
        });



        var fields = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel',{

            frame : true,
            title : 'Editing Zone',
            width : 1000,
            fieldDefaults : {
                msgTarget : 'side',
                labelWidth : 75
            },
            defaultType : 'textfield',
            defaults : {
                    anchor : '100%'
            },


            items : [
            //TaskName
            {
                fieldLabel : 'TaskName',
                name : 'task',
                allowBlank : false 
            },{
                xtype: 'combo',
                name : 'material',
                fieldLabel: 'Choose Material',
                store: states,
                queryMode: 'local',
                displayField: 'name',
                valueField: 'abbr'
            },{

                xtype:'datefield',
                anchor : '100%',
                disabledDays:  [0, 6],
                fieldLabel : 'date_debut'

            },{
                xtype : 'hiddenfield',
                name : 'id'


            }],
                layout: 'hbox',
                buttons: [{
                    text: 'Reset',
                    handler: function() {
                        this.up('form').getForm().reset();
                    }
                    }, {
                        text: 'Submit',
                        formBind: true, //only enabled once the form is valid

                        handler: function() {


                            var id =this.up('form').getForm().findField('id');
                            var id2 = id.getValue();
                            var node  = tree.getSelectionModel().getSelection();

                            alert(node);
                        }

            }],

        });
        fields.render('mesfields');
        tree.render('mongrid');


});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure with the error, cause i did not test your code...

but from this forum, i got conclusion that `Ext.require` is include a script from `file system`...
like

```
Ext.require([
    'Ext.form.*',
    'Ext.tree.*',
]);
```

it's mean include all js in `src/form/` and `src/tree/` [more info](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0-beta3/docs/api/Ext.Loader.html)

the error what you get is because `var newNode = Ext.create('Ext.tree.TreeNode',{`
and there is not a TreeNode.js in `C:\xampp\htdocs\ext-4b3\src\tree` (my local).

Answer (score 8):

I assume that this was originally 3.x code that you are converting to 4.0?  The TreeNode class no longer exists in 4.0.  Instead you would create a standard Model instance and append that to your tree.  In 4.0 the tree's model (what were records in 3.x) get "decorated" with the new NodeInterface class, meaning that your model objects will also have a node API when they are used in the tree.  I.e., no need for a TreeNode object separate from the Model itself.

Answer (score 7):

Hi I'd had a similar problem and looking in the doc found:

Ext.data.NodeInterface, is a node from the treePanel in my case I get the root node and add a child by the method apendChild

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    loadMask: true,
    url: 'index.php?X=1',
    success: function (resp) {
        var t = Ext.decode(resp.responseText);
        root = Ext.getCmp('tree-panel').getRootNode(); //get the root node
        for (i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
            root.appendChild({
                id: i,
                text: t[i],
                leaf: true
            }); //add childs
        }
        Ext.get(document.body).unmask();
    }
});
```

I can see its easer. NodeInterface has other more usefull methods :)